# I am trying to add checkbox in admin grid - edit in custom module....getting error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to add checkbox in admin grid - edit in custom module....getting error "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Form_Helper_Data' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pragati-core-theme/magento/app/Mage.php on line 546" Need Help

Comment: Could you add your config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Mage_Form_Helper_Data isn't standard Magento helper. Seems like there is an error in the config.xml file of your custom module in the section where you init helpers. It would be better if you post the content of your config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using -

```
Mage::helper('form')->somefunction();
```

some where in your custom module Which was showing the error. 
Instead of this you need to use -

```
Mage::helper('custommodulename')->somefunction();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ohh My GoD! Thanks a lot you resolved my error. I am so happy, I have wasted lot of time for such a small issue. :) Again thanks.